# Why is mysql generating garbled text with utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation?

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

I have a mediumtext column in a mysql database with a utf8mb4 collation:

comments mediumtext utf8mb4_unicode_ci

When I perform a mysql ENCODE the text is saved to the database column:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (ENCODE('test', 'abc'));
```

However, when I try to DECODE the text it's output is garbled:

```
SELECT DECODE(comments,'abc') FROM mytable WHERE 1
```

This example would display:

�1�= g3���

If I change the column to latin1_swedish_ci then everything works correctly as it should and "test" is displayed. Note, I am saving inputting the "test" text through a php form but not processing the data in any way.

1 - Any ideas as to why this is occurring?

2 - Is there anyway to decode the garbled text? I tried several methods to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the string literal is defaulting to latin1.  Try this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (ENCODE(_utf8mb4'test', 'abc'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the exact same result: �1�= g3���

Answer (score 0):

Do not put non-text in a text column.

`ENCODE` generates binary information, so put it into a binary column, such as `MEDIUMBLOB`.